# Где хранит данные alasql?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, alasql

Alasql хранит данные в памяти браузера или на жёстком диске пользоватля?
И если не сложно можно немножко статей про alasql, тема интересная и хочется в ней разобраться)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В настоящий момент AlaSQL может работать в нескольких режимах:

- In-memory - основной режим, когда все данные и таблицы хранятся в памяти браузера или Node.js
- Кроме этого есть несколько адаптеров (надеюсь, что получится расширить их число): LocalStorage, FileStorage и IndexedDB
- Есть возможность написать свое расширение для хранения информации на других источниках.

Есть [несколько статей](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/People) на английском языке. В этом месяце (июнь 2015 года) у нас запланирована работа по улучшению качества примеров и документации, поэтому надеюсь, что будут и на русском языке.

Disclaimer: я - автор AlaSQL

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте эти, может поможет

1. http://jsperf.com/alasql-js-vs-websql/7
2. http://dailyjs.com/2014/11/06/alasql/
3. http://alasql.org/
4. https://github.com/agershun/alasql
5. http://www.slideshare.net/AndreyGershun/alasql-manual-141220-1